# How to handle different coordinates in different nodes in Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a snake clone, and I use few coordinates system in that. One is coordinates in map node, another is world node, where everything that scrolls resides and one is scene - where my snake head resides.

The problem is with converting points from one system to another. It can become very tedious to nest from one system to another and this also leads me to having to calculate all positions in scene class.

Take for example the code:

```
CGPoint tempPoint = [self convertPoint:[self convertPoint:[self.map nextWaypointForEnemyOnPosition:[self convertPoint:[self convertPoint:enemy.position fromNode:self.worldNode] toNode:self.map] andHeading:enemy.heading] fromNode:self.map] toNode:self.worldNode];
```

This gets out of hand very fast. How do I fix this and ease the point conversions?

Comment: Not being able to understand the situation. Can you give us a general mock-up of how the nodes are placed on the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all nodes that need to have coordinates compared on one layer (node) - this greatly simplifies things.